# All stored procedures listed by create date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Anyone know a simple query to grab a list of all stored procedures in a SQL 2005 database ordered by createdate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select * from sys.objects
where [type] = 'P'
order by create_date

Answer (score 7):

one way

```
select name from sys.procedures
where type = 'P'
order by create_date
```

Comment: Yup, but as you specify sys.procedures (as opposed to sys.objects) you don't need to write the condition type='P', do you? Cheers